# How was the area of this triangle found using the area of a right triangle?

Tags: triangles, area, coordinate-systems

[image]

This type of question came up in my exam a month back and its troubling me why I wasn't able to understand it. I vaguely recall my teacher explaining you could find the area using a right triangle but I don't think I understood it then or in the exam. I am aware of the formula, $$\frac{1}{2}[x_1(y_2-y_3)+x_2(y_3-y_1)+x_3(y_1-y_2)]$$
But I believe it won't be awarded marks if used because it's not part of the syllabus. So in summary,

> How was the area found using the area of a right triangle? Is there a visual way to see why it could be done?

Comment: Where does that formula come from? I don't think it applies in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a particular name to it and I can't find it on Wikipedia but I recall it's for areas of triangles in coordinate geometry and it's applicable when you know the coordinates of all 3 vertices. I would presume that it could be used here

Comment: If the points are $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(0,-1)$, as the diagram suggests, the formula results in a negative number.

Comment: [I found it](https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/area-of-triangle-in-coordinate-geometry/).  The formula is correct if you use absolute values.  It's derived by decomposing a triangle into differences of trapezoids based on the $x$-axis.  Very interesting.  But I'm glad you're interested in understanding the problem conceptually, rather than digging up a magic formula and applying it.  Your teacher won't allow off-syllabus formulas for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a right triangle with the origin, $(x_2, y_2)$ and $(x_3, y_3)$ as vertices, and another right triangle with vertices at the origin, $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_3, y_3)$.

Therefore the total area is big triangle - small triangle:

[image]

(a picture shows a thousand words)

Comment: Wow, It was plain in sight. Can't believe I couldn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: @AaryanPatil No problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

The area of the obtuse triangle can be represented as the difference between the area of the right triangle with vertices $(0;0)$, $(x_2;y_2)$ and $(x_3;y_3)$, and the area of the right triangle with vertices $(0;0)$, $(x_1;y_1)$ and $(x_3;y_3)$.

However, I think it's easier to just calculate the product of the lengths of both green and red segments, then divide it by $2$ in order to find the area of the obtuse triangle.
[image]